# Is 802.11g wifi enough for 2Mbps videoconferencing?

Tags: wifi, video-conferencing

Is connection of videoconference equipment with WiFi stations in bridge mode instead of wired connection will affect the videoconference quality? 
For the WiFi link used Ubiquiti NanoStation Loco2, 802.11g. Both APs are indoors.
VC codecs are Polycom HDX.

Comment: Yes, its probably enough, but you'll need QoS probably to make it reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, it should be more than enough bandwidth to handle a 2Mbit stream.

Long Answer:

1) You need to be sure that link is operating at 54Mbps, it may have negotiated down, check your signal strength.

2) If any other trafic will be using this same wireless link in order to make this reliable you will need QoS to make sure voice is serviced first, then video, with both configured to DROP packets during congestion, not queuing.

Comment: I'm not sure about signal strength, will 18-12 Mbps Tx and Rx rates be enough? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sure, probably. Take a look into better antennas for those bridges maybe.

Comment: Looks like that AirOS honors DSCP/TOS markings out of the box, you should be good here as long as the Polycoms are marking their packets which they should be, you may have to toggle that on.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that 2Mbit is 250 KB/s, which is not enough for streaming audio and video.

You're seeing serious packet loss because the packets are [presumably] being dropped to stay under that limit.

Comment: Just added comment into my question, after P.S.

Comment: Pretty sure he's saying the stream is 2Mbit, not the link.